# How to prove that "there is no linear transformationT:R3 to P2

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

Hello! I'm having trouble understanding how to approach this problem. All the questions before had a find $T[a b]$ and $T[\ldots ]$ and now I'm asked to explain this. Should I use the conditions needed for Linear transformation $(t(u+v)=T(u)+T(v),Tcu=cT(u))$ to prove it?

The question is "Prove that there is no linear transformation $T:R_3$ to $P2$ such that:

---

$T$[$2$ $1$ $0$ $]=1+x$, $T$[$3$ $0$ $2$ $]=2-x+x^2, T$[ $0$ $6$ $-8$ $]=-2+2x^2$

---

Answer (score 1):

$\boldsymbol{Hint}$:
$$6\left(\begin{matrix}
  2 \\1\\ 0\\
 \end{matrix}\right)-4\left(\begin{matrix}
  3 \\0\\ 2\\
 \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
  0\\6\\ -8\\
 \end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Ah! I think I get it! Thank u so much!